# Bitbucket clone to Sourcetree, repeatedly asking for password

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am completely new to Bitbucket and Sourcetree. I have received a repository from my college, when I log into Bitbucket I find it there with all necessary files. I would like to clone it, so i can work with it on my laptop, so I drag it from the website to the Sourcetree window and get requested Source URL, Destination path and Name. Here the problems start, I get repeatedly asked for password, but the password is correct. Do someone have any suggestions? I am running OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6

Thank you!

Comment: You must be added to the repository, ask your college to do that for you. If the repository is private you should use your address, not his address.

Comment: Thank you @mohessaid, I am added to the repository, I tired also with this URL where my username is appearing, no success.

Comment: Solved this in the end, but didn't know what I did. Perhaps added a keychain manually.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue on SourceTree 2.7.3 under OS-X 10.13.6. I was given access to a repository over https and had to clone it. Since even the cloning failed through SourceTree due to "password keep asking issues", I cloned it through Terminal which worked fine. Post that, I could open the locally cloned bitbucket repo through SourceTree, but any git remote operations continue to fail over "password keep asking issues".

I came across several possible workarounds through several posts like

> 1. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-bitbucket-password-on-windows/qaq-p/241278
> 2. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-login-and-password/qaq-p/146765
> 3. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/SourceTree-2-7-constantly-asks-for-credentials/qaq-p/711139
> 4. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-clone-to-Sourcetree-repeatedly-asking-for-password/qaq-p/704242#U919139

Suggested workarounds were

> 1. Using latest out of embedded or system git versions and reopened SourceTree
> 2. Upgraded SourceTree from 2.7.3 to 2.7.6
> 3. Clearing bitbucket entries from keychain and reopened SourceTree
> 4. Clearing bitbucket sourceTree cached passed file from ~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree/ and reopened SourceTree
> 5. **Did not** try to downgrade from 2.7.3 to 2.6.3 as suggested by one post wondering what worse might wait for me with an older version :-)
> 6. Even restarted the machine without any luck.

At this point, I noticed that my Mac's Gmail synching went offline after sometime due to login issues. Then I recalled that my Atlassian account address is the Gmail-id I used for OAuth integration with BitBucket User. And, sign-in to bitbucket was successful too through SourceTree's Accounts option. It is the subsequent git remote operations through SourceTree UI was suffering and now os-x Gmail synching too.

Then, I kept the password of Atlassian's user id(which is my Gmail id) to same as that of Gmail id. And, restarted the machine. Voila.. it all started working fine including Gmail synching and SourceTree.

Wondering if the password chosen for Atlassian account, which is the same as the Email-id used for its OAuth integration, did corrupt SourceTree's key-chain entries for HTTPS access. That sounds ridiculous and a critical bug. sigh!!!